# Have Spring Data JPA lookup matching entities for cascading

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How can I use Spring Data JPA with Hibernate 5.0.12 as vendor to match existing database entries onto unmanaged entities for cascading?

Say I have entities like these:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private Integer zip;
    private String city;
}

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    // implementation provided by Spring Data JPA
}
```

The instances originate from a JAXB unmarshaller, for our purposes let's assume:

```
public Person data(String name, Integer zip, String city) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName(name);

    Address address = new Address();
    address.setZip(zip);
    address.setCity(city);

    person.setAddress(address);

    return person;
}
```

Now I'd like this code to work as described above:

```
Person p1 = data("Alice", 12345, "Berlin");
Person p2 = data("Bob", 12345, "Berlin");

// create a row in person table and create a row in address table
personRepository.save(p1);

// this should only create a row in person 
// and assign existing address entity reference to it
personRepository.save(p2);
```

Naturally the code fails due to a *unique constraint violation* so I'm wondering if there's some way I can specify business keys for JPA to match my entities to existing rows in the database (e.g. the `zip`).

Comment: The only solution I come up with is to change the data method to actually check if the Address is already in db, retrieve the Address and set it in person object if exist or set a new Address object otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately I retrieve the data from `Jaxb2Marshaller#unmarshal` hence I don't think that's possible.

Comment: So then, create a service above jpa repo with the same method name _save_ that checks and replaces addresses before saving persons.